# Remove a choice from a picked statement

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

Basically what I'm trying to do, is to let the user enter a number between 1-3, and when that number is entered, an `if-statement` is going to execute..

However, I want this loop to go through all the cookies (which it does) til everyone is chosen and the same number cant be picked. Would appreciate it if you looked through my code and could explain how I should be doing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string luck;
    int cookies = 3;
    int choice;
    int *taken;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        cout << "What cookie do you want?";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1) {
            cout << "Tomorrow is a day";
        }
        if (choice == 2) {
            cout << "Tomorrow can be cool";
        }
        if (choice == 3) {
            cout << "Summer is coming";
        }
        choice--; //not working though, something wrong im doing i guess.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you supply same inputs and outputs?  What happens if I enter 3?  What happens if I enter 1?  what happens is I enter 10?

Comment: How do you _expect_ `choice--;` to work at all? Clearly, the value of this variable is overwritten in the next loop.

Comment: Sorry, my above comment was supposed to be "Can you supply `some` inputs and outputs?"  I'm confused by quite a bit of your code so starting with what you're expecting it to do will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need a container to keep track of what has been taken.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string luck;
    int choice;
    std::map< int, std::string > cookies {
       { 1, "Tomorrow is a day" },
       { 2, "Tomorrow can be cool" },
       { 3, "Summer is coming" }
    };

    while( cookies.size() ) {
        cout << "What cookie do you want? [";
        for_each( cookies.begin(), cookies.end(), []( std::map< int, string >::value_type & v ) { cout << v.first << ','; } );
        cout << ']';
        cin >> choice;

        std::map< int, std::string >::iterator iter( cookies.find( choice ) );
        if( iter == cookies.end() )
            cout << "Sorry, that cookie has been taken" << endl;
        else {
            cout << iter->second << endl;
            cookies.erase( iter );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice one. You could also add a check for out of range choices.